# How to update the status bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

My program keeps track of the number of characters and lines in the text box. I am trying to create a status bar that displays this information to the user. The problem is that when the status bar updates, it does not replace the old information, but simply adds it to the line.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int numChars = TextBox.Text.Length;
    int numLines = TextBox.LineCount;
    TextBlock statusText = new TextBlock();

    statusText.Text = "Line " + (numLines) + ", Char " + (numChars);
    Status.Items.Add(statusText);
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you 'Add' it to the status bar instead of 'Clearing' it first? The code nowhere states that old items should be cleared or removed, so they naturally stay.

Comment: @CShark ahh that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @asa Why do you add TextBlock manually? It would be much easier to add TextBlock in xaml and just update Text in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding new `TextBlock` to the `StatusBar` without clearing its items. Try clearing the items before adding a new one:

```
Status.Items.Clear();
Status.Items.Add(statusText);
```

However, a better solution would be to re-use the same `TextBlock`, instead of adding&clearing it:

```
// xaml:
<StatusBar>
    <StatusBarItem>
        <TextBlock Name="status" />
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>

// code behind:
status.Text = "...";
```

Comment: Just found out about this. Thanks

Comment: `{Binding}` would definitively be the better solution. However, OP seems to be working on what looks like reminiscent of WinForms.